# Calculate the length of a string in a specific file format with perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to both learn perl and use it in my research. I need to do a simple task which is counting the number of sequences and their lengths in a file such as follow:

```
>sequence1
ATCGATCGATCG
>sequence2
AAAATTTT
>sequence3
CCCCGGGG
```

The output should look like this:

```
sequence1 12
sequence2 8
sequence3 8
Total number of sequences = 3
```

This is the code I have written which is very crude and simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my ($input, $output) = @ARGV; 

open(INFILE, '<', $input) or die "Can't open $input, $!\n"; # Open a file for reading.
open(OUTFILE, '>', $output) or die "Can't open $output, $!"; # Open a file for writing.

while (<INFILE>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^>/)
    {
        my $number_of_sequences++;
    }else{
        my length = length ($input);
    }
}
print length, number_of_sequences;

close (INFILE);
```

I'd be grateful if you could give me some hints, for example, in the else block, when I use the length function, I am not sure what argument I should pass into it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Oh, sorry, indeed, it has errors, that's why I am asking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing out just the last length, not each sequence length, and you want to catch the sequence names as you go:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my ($input, $output) = @ARGV; 
my ($lastSeq, $number_of_sequences) = ('', 0);

open(INFILE, '<', $input) or die "Can't open $input, $!\n"; # Open a file for reading.

# You never use OUTFILE
# open(OUTFILE, '>', $output) or die "Can't open $output, $!"; # Open a file for writing.

while (<INFILE>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^>(.+)/)
    {
        $lastSeq = $1;
        $number_of_sequences++;
    } 
    else
    {
        my $length = length($_);
        print "$lastSeq $length\n";
    }
}

print "Total number of sequences = $number_of_sequences\n";

close (INFILE);
```

Comment: How can I print the output into a separate file using OUTFile filehandle?

Comment: `print OUTFILE "$lastSeq $length\n;` and `print OUTFILE "Total number of sequences = $number_of_sequences\n";`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Excuse me, would you mind explaining this part of the code you have added: /^>(.+), what is the function of (.+)? I also am wondering about this part of the code: $lastSeq = $1. is $1 a new variable? as far as I know, $_ variable is set for the contents of the current line, is that correct?

Comment: We're capturing (`(...)`) one or more characters (`.` matches anything we're going to find in a line of text, `+` means "one or more"). See the ["capturing matches"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Extracting-matches) section of the Perl regular expression tutorial.

Comment: In the $lastSeq = $1, could you also write $lastSeq = $_? is there a special reason that you have used $1? I think the purpose is to store the name of each sequence in a variable, is that right?

Comment: Yes. We're storing the characters matched between the parentheses, not the whole line with the `>` included. `$1` means "the first captured group". Again, check out the "capturing matches" link.

Comment: The script works perfectly when I use it without the OUTFILE option, but with OUTFILE, it returns this error: Global symbol "$length" requires explicit package name at ./get_fasta_length.pl line 27.

Comment: `OUTFILE` is almost certainly not the whole problem. The updated, now-failing script probably deserves its own question.

Comment: Sorry, I could fix it, it was a minor bug from my side, must be more careful from now and on.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have indicated that you want feedback on your program, here goes:

```
my ($input, $output) = @ARGV; 

open(INFILE, '<', $input) or die "Can't open $input, $!\n"; # Open a file for reading.
open(OUTFILE, '>', $output) or die "Can't open $output, $!"; # Open a file for writing.
```

Personally, I think when dealing with a simple input/output file relation, it is best to just use the diamond operator and standard output. That means that you read from the special file handle `<>`, commonly referred to as "the diamond operator", and you print to STDOUT, which is the default output. If you want to save the output in a file, just use shell redirection:

```
perl program.pl input.txt > output.txt
```

In this part:

```
    my $number_of_sequences++;
```

you are creating a new variable. This variable will go out of scope as soon as you leave the block `{ .... }`, in this case: the if-block.

In this part:

```
    my length = length ($input);
```

you forgot the `$` sigil. You are also using `length` on the file name, not the line you read. If you want to read a line from your input, you must use the file handle:

```
my $length = length(<INFILE>);
```

Although this will also include the newline in the length.

Here you have forgotten the sigils again:

```
print length, number_of_sequences;
```

And of course, this will not create the expected output. It will print something like `sequence112`.

Recommendations:

- Use a `while (<>)` loop to read your input. This is the idiomatic method to use.
- You do not need to keep a count of your input lines, there is a line count variable: `$.`. Though keep in mind that it will also count "bad" lines, like blank lines or headers. Using your own variable will allow you to account for such things.
- Remember to `chomp` the line before finding out its length. Or use an alternative method that only counts the characters you want: `my $length = ( <> =~ tr/ATCG// )` This will read a line, count the letters ATGC, return the count and discard the read line.

Summary:

```
use strict;
use warnings;   # always use these two pragmas

my $count;
while (<>) {
    next unless /^>/;  # ignore non-header lines
    $count++;          # increment counter
    chomp;    
    my $length = (<> =~ tr/ATCG//);   # get length of next line
    s/^>(\S+)/$1 $length\n/;              # remove > and insert length
} continue {
        print;             # print to STDOUT
    }
print "Total number is sequences = $count\n";
```

Note the use of `continue` here, which will allow us to skip a line that we do not want to process, but that will still get printed.

And as I said above, you can redirect this to a file if you want.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you need to change your inner loop to this:

```
...
  chomp;
  if (/^>/)
  {
      $number_of_sequences++;
      $sequence_name = $_;
  }else{
      print "$sequence_name ", length($input), "\n";
  }
...
```

Note the following:

- The `my` declaration has been removed from `$number_of_sequences`
- The sequence name is captured in the variable `$sequence_name`. It is used later when the next line is read.

To make the script run under strict mode, you can add `my` declarations for `$number_of_sequences` and `$sequence_name` *outside* of the loop:

```
my $sequence_name;
my $number_of_sequences = 0;
while (<INFILE>) {
 ...(as above)...
}
print "Total number of sequences: $number_of_sequences\n";
```

The `my` keyword declares a new *lexically scoped* variable - i.e. a variable which only exists within a certain block of code, and every time that block of code is entered, a new version of that variable is created. Since you want to have the value of `$sequence_name` carry over from one loop iteration to the next you need to place the `my` outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($file, $line, $length, $tag, $count);


$file = $ARGV[0];

open (FILE, "$file") or print"can't open file $file\n";
while (<FILE>){
    $line=$_;
    chomp $line;

    if ($line=~/^>/){
        $tag = $line;
    }
    else{
        $length = length ($line);
        $count=1;
    }
    if ($count==1){
        print "$tag\t$length\n";
        $count=0
    }
}

close FILE;
```